# Is person name a correct phrase?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

is it formal and correct to say (person name) or (license number)

or it is wrong and should I say person's name and license's name?

Comment: We usually refer to **a person's name** and **a licence number** (not licence name).

Comment: Perhaps you are enquiring as to a person's preferred name (Bob instead of Robert) vs their legal name (such as that which would appear on a passport/license)?

Comment: It might be better to use _personal name_.

Comment: It also depends on usage. For example, to label a text box in software, grammar is oft abandoned in favor of brevity.

Comment: Can you give a full example in a sentence of how you want to use this phrase.  Normally just "Name" is sufficient, in context..  See also https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/